# Passing Command Line Arguments to internet explorer via VB

Tags: internet-explorer, vba, command-line

I've got an app that my client wants to open a kiosk window to ie on startup that goes to their corporate internet.  Vb isn't my thing but they wanted it integrated into their current program and I figured it would be easy so I've got

```
Shell ("explorer.exe http://www.corporateintranet.com")
```

and command line thing that needs to be passed is -k

Can't figure out where in the hell to drop this to make it work.  Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to use -k, you will probably want to call `iexplore.exe` instead of `explorer.exe`.

Comment: Haha thanks for that, one step closer.  But start run: "iexplore -k http://www.corporateintranet.com"
works but when tried in the project I'm getting a file not found runtime error now

Comment: I think the Start/Run menu has a special exception for knowing where iexplore.exe is located (for backwards compatibility). In your program you may need to specify the full path to iexplore.exe.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, not the most elegant but it'll do:

```
Shell ("C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe -k http://www.corporateintranet.com")
```

Or less hardcoded

```
Shell ("iexplore.exe -k http://www.corporateintranet.com")
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to hard code the path for iexplore.exe; the system should know where to find it. Indeed, hard-coding the path could actually break your program in the future -- 64-bit OSes may place apps in different directories than you're used to.

Answer (score 0):

You have it right now but I think you are missing the closing quote after iexplore.exe

You may also want to take out the [space]-k, set the zoom level to what will work for you in kiosk mode and then put the [space]-k back in. I am guessing there is a parameter or argument as they call it to pass the opening zoom level to iexplore but don't know how to do that yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late. But for whoever comes to this topic in the future, here is my suggestion: use the ShellExecute Function from the Shell32.dll

Example:

```
ShellExecute(Application.hwnd, "open", "http://www.corporateintranet.com", vbNullString, vbNullString, SW_SHOWNORMAL)
```

Here is the declaration to put in a module:

```
Public Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpOperation As String, ByVal lpFile As String, ByVal lpParameters As String, ByVal lpDirectory As String, ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long
Public Const SW_SHOW = 5
Public Const SW_SHOWDEFAULT = 10
Public Const SW_SHOWNORMAL = 1
```